# Comparing dates in php having issues

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date

I'm trying to compare 2 dates with the usual code.

```
$date1 = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['ad_date']));

$date = $_GET['date'];

 if($date1 > strtotime($date)){
   echo ("Yes");
 }else{
   echo ("No");
 }
```

The `row['ad_date']` has "Y-m-d" format and the `$_GET['date']` has "d-m-Y" format.

PHP prints YES only when the **MONTH** of the `$_GET['date']` is lower than the **DAY** of `$row['date']`

When I echo both, after all the changes of the format, the format seems the same:
`13/12/2013 (date1) - 01/12/2013(date)`

The `$_GET['date']` is from the calendar of the `ui.js` jQuery and the `$row['date']` from mysql.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing straight string comparison, you should use strtotime to parse the date string to epoch time so you can compare them with numerical comparison.

```
$date1 = strtotime($row['ad_date']);
$date = strtotime($_GET['date']);

echo "{$row['ad_date']} -> {$date1}<br>";
echo "{$_GET['date']} -> {$date}<br>";

if($date1 > $date){
    echo ("Yes");
}else{
    echo ("No");
}
```

Comment: As you can see i use strtotime in line 1 of code to $row['date'] and in if condition strtotime for the date.

Comment: date() returns string.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php strtotime returns int

Comment: But your $date1 is still a string as you did a date() after strtotime()

Comment: Hmmm, so what i have to do? Didnt get the solution yet, sorry

Comment: Again a problem. Now it prints No only when the day from calendar is the same as the month of $row['date']. I copy/pasted your edit

Comment: @satafaka You should do some debugging output to aid with debugging.  I edited the code above, try to use that and see if you can get a better understanding as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot easier using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects as they are comparable:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($row['ad_date']);
$date2 = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d-m-Y",  $_GET['date']);
if($date1 > $date2){
  echo ("Yes");
}else{
  echo ("No");
}
```